# How can I identify which computers a USB drive has been used on?

Tags: forensics, usb-drive

Is there a way to find out in which and/or how many computers a USB flash disk entered.
And if its possible can we find out how many times a file was read/edited.
I heard that its possible , but I cant find a program  to do it.

Comment: What is your Operating system?

Comment: Windows / Linux(Kali - Backtrack)

Comment: Do you have access to specific workstations or only the USB? From the USB alone you will not find this, but some host OSes may leave trails or entries. USB devices, like iPods will record system identifiers because of syncing processes, but normally not a "standard" run of the mill usb device.

Comment: A modern, high tech version of an age old question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removable devices including USB sticks don't store this information.

You can perhaps find some specific products which implement an auditing / logging technology to remember the number / type of devices it has been plugged in, but if your specific device don't implement it then you can't.

Comment: And even if they do, it could be spoofed.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using (most flavours of) Linux, then the /var/log/messages folder will keep a record of the device that was inserted.

> May 20 16:04:44 c41111m kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
>
> May 20 16:04:45 c41111m kernel: [27978.113444] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5151
>
> May 20 16:04:45 c41111m kernel: [27978.113453] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
>
> May 20 16:04:45 c41111m kernel: [27978.113458] usb 2-1: Product: Cruzer Micro
>
> May 20 16:04:45 c41111m kernel: [27978.113462] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk
>
> May 20 16:04:45 c41111m kernel: [27978.113466] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 240103055311B652

See the **serial number** in the last entry.  That's unique for a device with that make and model.

Comment: I think he actually wants to check the information in the USB, instead of the machines it was inserted in.